# Ubuntu 12.04.01 does not identify USB Bluetooth

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I am trying to use a bluetooth USB, but Ubuntu 12.04.01 does not identify it. How to make external USB bluetooth dongle work with Ubuntu 12.04.01.

**[Edit1]**

Results of lsusb
[image]

Comment: what you got at lsusb ?

Comment: Ubuntu does not identify the external USB bluetooth.

Comment: There the problem comes . what branded bluetooth it is ?

Comment: I checked the package it is Tech-Com SSD-BT-819 and it is working fine on Windows 7. I am noob to Ubunu making transition from windows to Linux.

Comment: I think you need to install the drivers.something like custom drivers.

Comment: Please post the results of `lsusb` as @Jai asked ;) See http://askubuntu.com/questions/184475/dell-laptops-bluetooth-isnt-detected-by-ubuntu for pointers (you need to find the hardware ID before anyone can help).

Comment: @Rinzwind Please find attached image of `lsusb` in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try

add "blacklist hci_usb" to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf, and add "hci_usb reset=1" to /etc/modules

Comment: I tried it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

another idea if this fails is to look for a suitable firmware and update the firmware of your dongle via dfutool. I just mentioned this as an annotation, haven't had problems with bluetooth devices myself.